# Improving reliability of a server running programs in Interactive Services?

Tags: service, limit, windows-server-2012, interactive

I have a bunch of programs that i run as services in FireDaemon (30+ programs). They all "interact" with the desktop as they have a GUI. I usually check the status and change parameters every now and then by going into the Interactive Services via the Detection message.

The server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 and has plenty of resources (20 cores, 72GB ram, plenty of I/O) and usually is very stable. However, if i am in Interactive Services looking at the program statuses or/and modifying anything it frequently locks me out and i cannot get back onto the server. It is essentially frozen.

How can i increase the stability? Is there something i can do to add more resources to the Interactive Services? Is there a limit to how many programs i can run in interactive services? 
Any insight helps - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either probably already know this or have seen this since you're using FireDaemon Pro, but they have a free techinical preview of a Zero Session viewer that does just that. We have the same issue and when zero session causes problems it's almost like somebody pulled the network cable to that server.

http://support.firedaemon.com/news/24/firedaemon-session-0-viewer-pre-release-now-available.aspx

So far, so good with their session 0 viewer.